# Переключение группы пользователей OpenCart

Tags: mysql, opencart, ocstore

Пользователь может переключаться между различными группами(с помощью модуля). После выбора группы идёт запрос в БД на изменение группы пользователя, далее цены должны выводиться из вкладки редактирования товара "Акции"(если заданы цены товара для данной группы), но они остаются старыми до следующей перезагрузки страницы.

Не смотря на то, что модуль переключения групп находится в шапке сайта, и должен загрузиться первым, а только потом товары в категории, обновления цен не происходит с первой загрузки страницы.

Можно ли как-то всё-таки загружать цены только после изменения группы пользователя?